# Ansible: Use an integer across different playbooks, increment it on each use

Tags: ansible

I'm fairly new to ansible.

I need a counter that increments by 1 on each run of any one of multiple playbooks. The counter needs to be stored on the machine running the playbook. I have a way to do this, but it feels long winded. I want to know what best practice should be.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
---
- name: increment number
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  vars:
   request_id: "{{ lookup('file', '/path/counter.txt') }}"
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
   - debug: msg="request id is: {{ request_id }}"
   - name: increment number in file
     copy: content={{ request_id | int + 1 }} dest=/path/counter.txt
```

How should I be doing this? Using a fact or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simpler way doing this. Since Ansible is stateless you need to store your counter int somewhere, for example a file like you did.

You can use Ansibles [fact caching](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching). While that might look cleaner it is more effort to set it up. For fact caching you need to install Redis.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much!